# Resgatar valores de um SESSION

Tags: php

Estou tentando trazer através do `<?php include ''.$prod_04.'php'; ?>` mas não estou tendo retorno do conteúdo cadastrado na `$_SESSION['hab_prod_04']`.

Já verifique usando `<?php echo $prod_04 ?>`, e esta sendo gravado na `$_SESSION['hab_prod_04']` as alterações desejada.

Estou usando o seguinte código para efetuar a alteração:

```
    <?php
    $botao=$_POST['enter'];
    if($botao=="Cadastrar"){
        $prod_04 = $_POST["prod_04"];
    if(!empty($prod_04)) {
        $_SESSION['hab_prod_04']["prod_04"] = $prod_04 ;

    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= prod_cad_produtos_5_img.php'>
    <script language='javascript'>
    window.alert('Produto Cadastrado com sucesso!');
    </script>";
    }}
    ?>
    <form method="post">    
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_04" value="produto_04">
    <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="enter"/>
    </form>
```

Abaixo código da `$_SESSION['hab_prod_04']`:

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['hab_prod_04'])){ 

    $prod_04 = 'Vazio'; // Carrega esse conteúdo

    $_SESSION['hab_prod_04']['prod_04']=$prod_04;

    }else if(isset($_SESSION['hab_prod_04'])){

    $prod_04 = $_SESSION['hab_prod_04']["prod_04"];
    }
```

Se amigos puderem me ajudar a entender onde estou errando, para que não consiga visualizar o conteúdo com o `<?php include ''.$prod_04.'php'; ?>`, e com o `<?php echo $prod_04 ?>` eu consigo.

PS.: Quando uso `<?php include 'produto_04.php'; ?>`, funciona.

Desde já agradeço a todos a atenção dada ao meu problema.

Comment: tenho a impressão que o problema nem está na session. Não falta um ponto antes de `php'`? Troque o `include`  por `require` que já vai dar pra perceber.

Comment: De acordo com a edição ficou mais claro que é um ponto faltando antes de `php'` no include.

Comment: Valeu @Bacco, era isso mesmo a falta do ponto entre o concatenado e o php. Cara estou a dois dias tentando solucionar esse meu pipino...Rsrsrsrs... Pura falta de atenção de minha parte... Como se diz,"Quem esta de fora do problema, enxerga melhor a solução". Mais uma vez, BRIGADÃO.

Answer (score 0):

Com a ajuda do @Bacco, que reparou que estava faltando o ponto entre o concatenado e o php do include.

Posto o código funcionando abaixo.

```
<?php include ''.$prod_04.'.php'; ?>
```

Mais uma vez muito obrigado @Bacco.

Answer (score -1):

Em toda página que você necessita manipular os dados em uma sessão você deve usar a função `session_start();` para abrir uma sessão.

Isso vale tanto para o momento que você vai armazenar os dados em uma sessão:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = "54151405415345416515";
?>
```

Quando na hora de requisitar um dado de uma sessão:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user']
?>
```

Comment: Já esta inserido o `session_start();` em todas as paginas.